# POST and GET data are empty in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, post, webforms, postman

I'm having an issue with reading data from  requests in asp.net webforms.
I wrote a pretty simple page which inserts received data into the database, However when sending POST data to this page using applications like Postman or chrome extensions that do the same, the values for `Request.Form` and `Request.QueryString` are both empty. This does not happen when I'm debugging the application on my own system but happens when the page is uploaded to the host.
The only time that I'm able to receive anything is when I'm using `Request.QueryString` and data appended to the url like it's a GET request.

```
string value = "";  
//code that reads the data
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;                   
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)//read whatever is in POST request
    {
        value += Request.Form[keys[i]];
    }
     if(value.Length < 1) //if nothing is in there, try reading GET values
       value = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString.ToString());
Response.Write(value);//value contains nothing.
}
```

Comment: In Postman, one of the options for Body is form-data, are you using that one when posting form values?

Comment: @erastl actually I was using the x-www-form-urlencoded option(using form-data does work). are there any significant differences? What has me wondering is the fact that using x-www-form-urlencoded causes no problems on my debugging system.

Comment: If you look at the http code in postman, form-data is using a different Content-Type. For x-www-form-urlencoded, you'll see "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", but for form-data its "Content-Type: multipart/form-data". I don't know if that impacts how .NET picks up Request.Form values, but there is a difference.